# paginating with one-to-many relation in django

Tags: python, django, templates, pagination

I have 1-many related models.

```
class Foo(models.Model):

    foo_data = models.IntegerField()

class Bar(models.Model):

    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name="bars")

    bar_data = models.IntegerField()

paginator = Paginator(Foo.objects.filter(id=foo_id), 10)
page = 1
foos = paginator.page(page)
```

I need to display bar's data for each foo object in django template.
What's the prefered approach and how?

1. perform DB Query from the template (inclusion_tag or something?)
2. perform neccessary DB query in the view and pass that to the template somehow

Comment: Its better to do pagination in view than in template.

Comment: do you mean you need paginate bars too?

Comment: I need to display foo.bars in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a property in Foo class to return the related Bars:

```
class Foo(models.Model):

    foo_data = models.IntegerField()

    def _get_bars(self):
        return self.bars.all()
    bars = property(_get_bars)
```

then use {% for bar in foo.bars %} in the template

**edit:** or you could just use {% for bar in foo.bars.all %} in template I think, properties are useful if you need to do some extra filtering but not really needed here if you want all of them.